# Can BIND setup with only A names and fully qualified host names work properly?

Tags: linux, domain-name-system, bind, internal-dns

I recently came across a zone file for BIND which used only `A`ddress records with fully qualified domain names for each IP.

Example snippet:

```
subdomain1.example.com. IN A 192.168.1.10
subdomain2.example.com. IN A 192.168.1.10
subdomain3.example.com. IN A 192.168.1.10
```

There are also multiple fully qualified names resolving to the same IP addresses.

Is there a issue with this configuration? (i.e. not using CNAME or ALIAS?)

Can this be done or will it cause issues?

Since I am not an expert I assume some issues include:

- Reverse lookup. (first response is considered correct?)
- Certificates (if not first response then cert error?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is only a forward zone and as [@bodgit answered](https://serverfault.com/a/938086/376810) that is perfectly valid for all use cases.

The main potential disadvantage of the above is an administrative one. For a single zone not too much of an issue but with many host names in many different domains much more so:  in case of a change of ip-address every `A` record with that ip-address will need to be updated, where  `CNAME` records will automatically follow the ip-address change of their target FQDN and would not need to be updated.

For a reverse zone, doing something almost similar is AFAIK also technically valid:

```
10.1.168.192.in-addr.arpa. IN PTR  subdomain1.example.com.
10.1.168.192.in-addr.arpa. IN PTR  subdomain2.example.com.
10.1.168.192.in-addr.arpa. IN PTR  subdomain3.example.com.
```

but **that won't have the effect people usually seem to expect**.

subdomain1.example.com. will always point to 192.168.1.10 but the reverse lookup will *most of the time* NOT point back to subdomain1.example.com.
The above will become a [round-robin DNS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-robin_DNS) record where:

- 1/3 of the responses will return an *"incorrect"* response of subdomain2.example.com.
- 1/3 of the responses will return an also  *"incorrect"* response of subdomain3.example.com.
- only a 33% chance exists that the *"correct"* response of subdomain1.example.com. will be seen.

Comment: What do you think is "incorrect" with 2/3 of the responses? Actually, the responses will return all three names. The only specific use case where a match between forward and reverse DNS is mandatory is with mail transport agents; and AFAIR there all tests are that the originla forard name be *among* the rDNS results ...

Answer (score 6):

It's perfectly valid to have multiple A records pointing to the same IP. Reverse lookup has nothing to do with it; as that would a) be in a separate zone and b) would be using PTR records. Certificates are also irrelevant here.